# React js Import image issue

Tags: reactjs

Help me to solve React js Import image issue the image is not working I try too many times console log error images and folder structure.

If I put direct server URL the images is visible

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import '../assets/css/bootstrap.css';
    import '../assets/css/home.css';
    import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import logo from '../assets/img/donut-logo.jpg';


    class Home extends Component {
        render() {
            return (

                <main>
                    <div className="container-fluid mainheader">
                        <div className="container mainheader-wrapper">
                             <img src="{logo}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                        <div className="container mainheader-btn">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <a href={FlowRouter.url('login')}>Login</a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <a href={FlowRouter.url('register')}>Register</a>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                </main>
            )
        }
    }

    Home.propTypes = {};
    Home.defaultProps = {};

export default Home;
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/onDQu.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ripwM.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9TEP.png
```

Comment: Just give me the rough view of your folder structure?

Comment: Please post errors as text not screenshots.

Comment: Can you add folder structure to figure out what is an issue.

Comment: @Prashant The error in your image is for seeking the image named donut-logo.jpg, Are you sure that you are getting the correct message?

Comment: @Upasana yes same image we are using

Comment: @PrashantSaxena , One quick question, does your 'assets' folder is at same level as of your 'src' folder? If not, then try putting them at same level and access it directly in image 'src' attribute like <img src="../assets/imageLogo.jpg"/>

Comment: @Upasana still not working.

Comment: Can you share your project structure?

Comment: @Upasana folder structure images added please check.

Comment: @PrashantSaxena I am not able to find your image. Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using web pack for bundling.
If you used then please follow the below thing.

Add url-loader in the config file of your webpack as follows.

```
{
    test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
    options: {
      mimetype: 'image/png'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using Meteor with ReactJS.

Try to create a public folder in the root directory (same level as client, server, import), place your image in the public folder and then try to import it.